# Adding eventListener to the navigation list items

Tags: javascript, navigation, event-listener

***updating question as a part of it is solved***

I have been trying to add eventListener to all the list items in navbar.   problem is in this line

> items[i].classList.add('active'); // not working

---

```html
  <li class="active ac"><a href='#'>A</a></li>
<li class=" ac"><a href='/B'>B</a></li>
<li class=" ac"><a href='/C'>C</a></li>

<script>
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName('ac');
       
        console.log(items[0].classList); // showing {active, ac}
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
        {    
           

            items[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                    


                    for(var j=0;j<items.length;j++)
                        items[j].classList.remove('active');

                    items[i].classList.add('active'); // not working
                    
                    
             }, false);
        }
       
    </script>
```

Comment: it should be `document.addEventListener` and your 2nd parameter is wrong , should be an specific `id` or specific `class` name

Comment: yes I corrected somethings, like,                                                                `for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
        {    
            items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                   
                    for(var j=0;j<items.length;j++) 
                       items[j].classList.remove('active');
                    this.classList.add('active');//.add('active');
                    // console.log(i);
                    
             }, false);
        }`

Comment: **in this inside for loop is not working (i.e. removing class 'active' from every items)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this order helps:

```
<li class="active ac"><a href='#'>A</a></li>
<li class=" ac"><a href='/B'>B</a></li>
<li class=" ac"><a href='/C'>C</a></li>

<script>
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName('ac');
       
        console.log(items[0].classList); // showing {active, ac}
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
         items[i].classList.add('active');
        console.log(i); // not printing anything.
        
          items[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{

                    for(var j=0;j<items.length;j++)
                        items[i].classList.remove('active');
                    
             }, false);
        
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: but in this case, without click also it will add active class

Comment: **this is working** `for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
        {    
            items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                  console.log(items.length);
                    for(var j=0;j<items.length;j++){
                        // console.log(items[j]);
                    
                       items[j].classList.remove('active');
                    }
                    this.classList.add('active');
                    
                    
                    
             }, false);
        }`

Comment: If you want just to remove the class 'active' I would recommend you to use setTimeout() Method. Here is the link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
I was not using this keyword.
as i is undefined inside the function that's why it was not working.

```html
 for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
        {    
            items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                 
                    for(var j=0;j<items.length;j++){
                      
                       items[j].classList.remove('active');
                    }
                    this.classList.add('active');
                    
                    
                    
             }, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        item.classList.add('active')
        Array.from(items).forEach(elem => {
            elem !== item && elem.classList.contains('active') ? elem.classList.remove('active') : null
        })
    })
})
```